# SQL Server Integration services task condition

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to do something in SSIS , but I am having an error message. This is the thing:

I am translating an Access project into a SSIS project. At one point I found a query like this:

```
Insert into table A (column1, column2...)
from table B
where B.column2 = "value"
```

I suppose I need to create a workflow like this:

**Flat file source -> Data conversion -> OLE DB Destination**

by the way, my data source is a csv file.

The question is, how can I handle the **where** clause in the query with this structure?

I tried by putting the sql sentence in the destination source but I always obtained the same error message.

I have to add that I am new with SSIS and this is my first assignment with this tool.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These steps can be a good and simple option for you;

1. Create a package with a "Data Flow Task" inside
2. In your data flow task, use a "Flat File Source" component using coma delimition. Due to this is a flat file, you will have to read the file till end of it
3. Use a "Conditional Split" component to filter rows according to your criteria
4. Link your positive output to next steps, ignore the other
5. If you need, you can use "Data Conversion" component to convert source data
6. Insert data to "OLE DB Destination"

Hope this helps